# Kubernetes & insecure docker registries

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trailing Kubernetes on AWS, and I have a cluster set up, but having trouble creating an application by pulling a docker image from an insecure repo.

When I created the cluster, I ensured that the environment variable `KUBE_ENABLE_INSECURE_REGISTRY=true` was set to true. But I still don't seem to be able to pull from this repo.

The logs show (edited application name and registry URL):

> Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "****"
> with ErrImagePull: "API error (500): unable to ping registry endpoint
> https://docker-registry.***.com:5000/v0/\nv2 ping attempt failed with
> error: Get https://docker-registry.***.com:5000/v2/: EOF\n v1 ping
> attempt failed with error: Get
> https://docker-registry.***.com:5000/v1/_ping: EOF\n"

Can anyone please advise on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/cluster/gce/config-default.sh#L85), it seams that, only registries on network 10.0.0.0/8 can be insecure, is your registry on this range? What about setting `EXTRA_DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry YOUR_REGISTRY_IP"` manually to docker environment file? Is that possible for you?

Comment: hi, i ended up creating a new cluster using "EXTRA_DOCKER_OPTS=" --insecure-registry". How would i have set this without needing to rebuild the cluster?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question? Also, I appreciate if you can explain how you create the cluster using "EXTRA_DOCKER_OPTS=" --insecure-registry".

Answer (score 0):

You can config it in each work node, add the file in each node **/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "experimental" : true,
  "insecure-registries" : [
    "your-registry.domain.name"
  ]
}
```

Then restart the docker at each node

```
service docker restart
```

Comment: You also need to provide an insecure registry port, see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry)